# LoadError when using bundle exec to run a script in Ruby 3 (using rvm)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rvm, ruby-3

The following Ruby script gives me a `LoadError` when it requires the `activesupport` gem, but everything else is showing me that it's installed.  I get the same error whether I run it through `bundle exec` or `rvm do`.

```
$ cat Gemfile | grep activesupport
gem 'activesupport'

$ bundle show activesupport
/Users/2b-software-mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/activesupport-7.0.6

$ bundle exec ruby my_ruby_script.rb
Can I find the gem?
#<Bundler::StubSpecification name=activesupport version=7.0.6 platform=ruby>
Can I require the gem?
my_ruby_script.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- activesupport (LoadError)
    from my_ruby_script.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

#### Script

```rb
puts 'Can I find the gem?'
puts Gem::Specification.find_all{ |g| g.name.include? 'activesupport' }
puts 'Can I require the gem?'
require 'activesupport'
```

#### Versions

- rvm 1.29.12
- ruby 3.1.2p20
- gem 3.3.7
- bundle 2.3.7
- macOS 13.5.2 (M2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem has to be loaded like this (note the underscore):

```
require "active_support"
```

Read about [Stand-Alone Active Support](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#stand-alone-active-support) in the Rails Guides.

Comment: What a fool I am!  Thanks for the help. 